# Efeito de subir tela

Tags: jquery, parallax

Pessoal como eu faço este efeito de paralax de subir a tela sobrepondo outra.

Ex. [Manutti](http://www.manutti.com/)

Basta rolar o mouse e verá a tela subir e passar sobre o banner central.

---

### Edição:

Ja li o post sobre o paralax mas não consegui entedê-lo. Gostaria se alguem poder colocar um exemplos simples semelhante a este onde se tem uma div no topo que é fixa, uma outra div no centro com uma imagem grande fixa também e uma outra div abaixo com um longo texto que ao rolar o mouse para cima ira sobrepor a div da imagem grande.

Comment: O nome disso é `parallax`.

Comment: @LuizVieira realmente é isto mesmo, mas peço desculpas pois não sabia como se chamava este tipo de efeito por isto não localizei este post que você citou. Muito Obrigado pela informação.

Comment: Não se preocupe, essas coisas acontecem. Pra isso que serve a comunidade ajudando com tais indicações. :) As vezes as pessoas se ofendem com um "voto pra fechar", mas a ideia é sempre ajudar quem pergunta enquanto se mantém a qualidade do conteúdo no site.